# $\log(x)+\log(y)$ with respect to $x+y$

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus, logarithms

This is probably a very dumb question, but say that we have the quantity $(x+y)$ which we can access directly, not knowing what $x$ and $y$ is separately. Can we obtain an expression for $\log(x)+\log(y)$?

Comment: $\log(x) + \log(y) = \log(xy),$ right? So if we can change the value of $xy$ without changing $x + y,$ then no

Comment: @StephenDonovan could u elaborate the last part?

Comment: Consider $x = 2, y = 2$ and $x = 1, y = 3.$ Both pairs give us $x + y = 4,$ but in the first case we have $xy = 4,$ and in the second $xy = 3.$ That would mean that our expression for $\log(xy)$ in terms of $x + y$ would need to give at least both the values $\log(4)$ and $\log(3)$ for $x + y = 4,$ which means that it can't be a function.

Comment: You can get an upper bound though, by using the monotonicity of log and the AM-GM.